# Java wrapper for Unix not working outside of current directory

Tags: java, unix

I created a trash can utility using Java that deletes a file and puts it in a trash can where it can be restored.

I want it to work so you can type `Del filename`and it will delete the file and `Undel filename` and it will undelete the file. So far so good....as long as you are in the directory that has the class files and the Del shell script.

I tried adding `PATH=/Users/username/Dropbox/CS211S/HW03_delete/:$PATH` to my .profile. Nada.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#                 
# Author:  me
# Date  :  10/02/12        
# Program Name: Del 
#                         

export CLASSPATH=/Users/username/Dropbox/CS211S/HW03_delete:$CLASSPATH 

(( $# == 0 )) && echo "usage: Del file-name(s)" && exit 1
Java Del $*
```

To run it, I have to be in the directory with Del and the class file and type `./Del filename` in Terminal. I should be able to type just `Del filename` but I for the life of me have no idea how to make it work...

If I do type just `Del filename` I get a command not found error!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not about java at all. It is about unix shell only. Put your script under `/bin`, add execution permissions for all relevant users and run it without mentioning of path, i.e. directly as you want: `Del`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is exporting the path to the `.profile`.

Type this in the terminal

```
gedit $HOME/.profile
```

Now change the line

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ; export PATH
```

into this.

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/username/Dropbox/CS211S/HW03_delete/:$PATH;
export PATH
```

Hope this helps. And this is sure about the UNIX only.